# What's the socially acceptable way to leave a Stream after using it?

Tags: c#

If you are designing an API, or even within your own code, and your method accepts a `Stream`, is it your method's duty to check the position and reset it to the beginning provided that `CanSeek` is `true` before using it?

If so, why isn't there a method that does all this on the `Stream` class itself?

Over the years I've been caught out a few times by assuming the `Stream` comes into my method in position 0.

And is it right to reset the `Stream` where possible after using it?

Alternatively, should `Stream`s always be copied around instead of passed around directly? Seems a bit excessive to me.

Comment: What do you mean with "copied around" ?

Comment: +1 for the title. I'm going to say *socially acceptable* during peer reviews from now on.

Comment: @HenkHolterman As in, `stream.CopyTo(copy);` before using an incoming stream, for example.

Comment: @LukePuplett, Stream.Copy to changes the position in the source stream, so it wouldn't solve anything...

Comment: You simply cannot assume that the stream *only* contains the data you are interested in.

Comment: What if I'm handing you a `Stream` that I've already seeked to correctly?  Why would you reset that for me "helpfully"?  Maybe I'm storing the data you want to read in the middle of another stream...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is it your method's duty to check the position and reset it to the beginning provided that CanSeek is true before using it?

No, in that case I would expect the calling code to prepare the stream correctly.

The most common patterns that share a stream over methods require that the pointer is left exactly after the last read/write, so this never comes up much.

But the best thing to *after* using it: do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

> is it your method's duty to check the position and reset it to the beginning provided that CanSeek is true before using it?

No, for two reasons:

- it's not always possible (e.g. if `CanSeek` is false), so it would be strange if you did it for some streams and not for others
- BCL classes don't do it. For instance, `StreamReader` closes the underlying stream when it is disposed, it doesn't restore it to its previous state.

Comment: That's interesting since `StreamReader` closing the stream is arguably not its responsibility to do so, and could be seen as worse than resetting to 0.

Comment: The StreamReader design has been discussed a lot, it's debatable. There are wrappers to circumvent this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to update the question since people have already cast votes but may not like this part :)

This is very interesting (thanks) and clearly shows the difference in thinking when designing reusable library style code vs. application code.

So if its the application's responsibility to prepare the `Stream` for the API (and it seems we all agree), then we can 'lift' the helpful logic into an extension method within the app.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to set the stream to position 0 if required.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// False if the stream is not at position 0 and does not support seek operations.
    /// </returns>
    public static bool TrySetPositionZero(this Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream.Position > 0)
        {
            if (stream.CanSeek)
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The difference between this and simply `stream.Position = 0` is that it has more chance of success since it will succeed on forward-only streams when already at position 0.